# Google Analytics unique purchases suddenly stopped working

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For some reason reporting of unique purchases has stopped working in google analytics for the past few days.

It has been working for over 6 months without a flaw, but all of a sudden (it seems since the last iphone app update) it has stopped recording unique purchases. I didn't modify anything related to the GA code since the last iphone release. 
I am viewing the unique purchases using the "Custom Reporting" in google analytics, using the  "Unique Purchases" metric, and "Day" dimension.

The analytics calls are integrated from an iphone app, and I make the ecommerce calls `addTransaction`, `addItem`  and `trackTransactions` - and they all return without a error when i debug through the iphone simulator.

I am following this document as reference:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/ios.html

Im not doing anything different to what the docos are saying.

Any assistance as to how i can figure out what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

martin

Comment: Where any filters recently added to the analytics profile?

Comment: no filters were added ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be that the Google analytics ecommerce tracking setting wasn't enabled on the account...

Weird thing is that it was working before, i guess Google fixed the bug and that caused ecommerce to be turned off.